# Are the Eisenstein series $G_4^2$ and $G_8$ equal?

Tags: modular-forms, zeta-functions

I know that both are in the 1-dimensional vector space $M_8$, so they must be linearly dependent. My instructor said they are equal, but I think the constant terms $(2\zeta(4))^2$ and $2\zeta(8)$ don't match up. What is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Is your instructor thinking of $E_4^2=E_8$?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series#Products_of_Eisenstein_series

Comment: If they equal, shouldn't the constant term match up though?

Comment: If your notation adheres to the Wikipedia entry's, then $G_4^2$ and $G_8$ are *not* equal, because, as you observe, $(2\zeta(4))^2\not=2\zeta(8)$.  Why don't you ask your instructor what he or she means in saying they are equal?

Comment: @BarryCipra Will do. Thank you!

Comment: Yes $\text{Dim }M_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z})) = 1+\lfloor k / 12 \rfloor$ if $ k \not \equiv 2 \bmod 12$ and $\text{Dim }M_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z})) = \lfloor k / 12 \rfloor$ otherwise, so that $\text{Dim  }M_8(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))=1$ and $G_4(\tau)^2 = \frac{4\zeta(4)^2}{2\zeta(8)} G_8(\tau)$ and your teacher is right to say $G_4,G_8$ are equal (up to a constant) @BarryCipra